# Google SignIn for iOS fails to build because it's looking for a file that doesn't exist

Tags: ios, google-signin

Google just updated their sign in library for ios to [version 3.0.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/release#2016-03-22_--_v300).
In the process, it looks like they also caused the library to fail to build with the error `ld: file not found: MY_APP_PATH/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_NSData+zlib.a`

What can I do to solve this?
I'm using Cocoapods.

Answer (score 2):

I mostly made this question so that there's a google-able answer on how to fix this issue.

Like I stated in the question above, the issue is caused by the March 22 2016 v3.0.0 update of the Google iOS libraries.

## What I believe caused my build error

The [Google Signin Podspec v3.0.0](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/GoogleSignIn/3.0.0/GoogleSignIn.podspec.json) (I don't actually recommend you follow that link given the performance issues surrounding how the Cocoapods ecosystem is architected) lists the library `GoogleUtilities` as a dependency.

```
"dependencies": {
    "GoogleUtilities": [
      "~> 1.0"
    ],
```

The `GoogleUtilities` [Podspec v1.2.0](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/GoogleUtilities/1.2.0/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json) makes these files available to those who import it:

```
"vendored_libraries": [
    "Libraries/libGTM_iPhone_external.a",
    "Libraries/libGTM_core_external.a",
    "Libraries/libGTM_UIFont+LineHeight_external.a",
    "Libraries/libGTM_SystemVersion_external.a",
    "Libraries/libGTM_StringEncoding_external.a",
    "Libraries/libGTM_RoundedRectPath_external.a",
    "Libraries/libGTM_Regex_external.a",
    "Libraries/libGTM_NSStringXML_external.a",
    "Libraries/libGTM_NSStringHTML_external.a",
    "Libraries/libGTM_NSScannerJSON_external.a",
    "Libraries/libGTM_NSDictionary+URLArguments_external.a",
    "Libraries/libGTM_NSData+zlib_external.a",
    "Libraries/libGTM_KVO_external.a",
    "Libraries/libGTM_GTMURLBuilder_external.a",
    "Libraries/libGTM_DebugUtils_external.a",
    "Libraries/libGTM_AddressBook_external.a",
    "Libraries/libGTMStackTrace_external.a"
  ],
```

Notice that `GoogleUtilities` does not make `libGTM_NSData+zlib` available. It's likely that the previous version of `GoogleUtilityies` did make that file available, but I'm not able to confirm that by looking at the previous version of the podspec due to the performance issues mentioned above.

## How I fixed my build error

I fixed the build error by rolling my GoogleSignIn dependency back to the previous version, `2.4.0`.

To do that, open your Podfile and replace

```
pod 'Google/SignIn'
```

with

```
pod 'GoogleSignIn', '2.4.0'
```

Do a project-wide search and replace that replaces `<Google/SignIn.h>` with `<GoogleSignIn.h>`.

Comment: Does anyone know how I can submit a bug report to the Google Sign In iOS team?

Comment: Hi! I have the same problem but your solution doesn't work for me!
I've always the error about the file libGTM_NSData+zlib!
I have also added on my Podfile the pod 'Google', '~> 2.0' because the libraries search others files in Pods/Google/Libraries.
Thanks!

Comment: I've created an issue on the google service examples on github, linking this question. https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/194

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the GoogleSignIn 3.0.0 release requires a newer version of some dependencies - running `pod install` wont pick up them up though, as they still satisfy the matching in the Podspec.

Could you try running `pod update` - that should fetch the latest version of all libraries.

Comment: There are updates for various pods that should resolve these issues - please try updating to the latest versions across the board!

Answer (score 0):

I've found that simply have to specify a previous version of `GoogleUtilities` in the Podfile of your application or where you are making the dependency with Google SignIn.

Like `'GoogleUtilities', '1.2.0'` Fixed the problems I was having.