# ld: file not found: /Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_NSData+zlib.a fix issue

Tags: ios, google-analytics, cocoapods

In Pod it is showing like this.

```
libGTM_NSData+zlib_external.a
```

[image]

While in Build settings, it looks as below

```
$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_NSData+zlib.a
```

In config, it shows as this.

```
-force_load $(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_NSData+zlib_external.a
```

**How can I remove error of not finding libGTM_NSData+zlib.a as I know new google library has libGTM_NSData+zlib_external.a only.**

I am using

```
pod 'Google/Analytics'
pod 'Google/SignIn'
```

in my Pod file.

Kindly give proper structure of removing such issue. I tried to rename and keeping all of same name as _external, it didn't solve the problem.

Final installation of Pods via Terminal shows Log as below

```
 Analyzing dependencies
    Downloading dependencies
    Installing AFNetworking (2.6.3)
    Installing AMScrollingNavbar (1.5.1)
    Installing Bolts (1.7.0)
    Installing ChartboostSDK (6.4.0)
    Installing Charts (2.2.4)
    Installing Crashlytics (3.7.0)
    Installing Fabric (1.6.7)
    Installing Google (2.0.3)
    Installing Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (7.7.1)
    Installing GoogleAnalytics (3.14.0)
    Installing GoogleAppUtilities (1.1.0)
    Installing GoogleAuthUtilities (2.0.0)
    Installing GoogleInterchangeUtilities (1.2.0)
    Installing GoogleNetworkingUtilities (1.2.0)
    Installing GoogleSignIn (3.0.0)
    Installing GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.1.0)
    Installing GoogleUtilities (1.2.0)
    Installing MMDrawerController (0.5.7)
    Installing Optimizely-iOS-SDK (1.4.2)
    Installing Parse (1.13.0)
    Installing SDWebImage (3.7.5)
    Installing Shapes (1.0.2)
    Installing SocketRocket (0.3.1-beta2)
    Installing libPusher (1.5)
    Installing pop (1.0.9)
    Generating Pods project
    Integrating client project
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm also getting same error. Any resolutions?

Comment: Yes, I solved it. @Meet

Comment: Please share ur resolution

Comment: ya sure, I will update answer. @Meet

Comment: @Meet, check my answer, what I did.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google SignIn for iOS fails to build because it's looking for a file that doesn't exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36168692/google-signin-for-ios-fails-to-build-because-its-looking-for-a-file-that-doesn)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open **Build Settings**
2. Go to **Framework Search Paths**
3. Leave only these two as shown in image, and remove all others, like **libGTM_NSData+zlib.a** or any other.

[image]

4. This inherited & Project Directory will cause automatically detection from Pods, and it will not more create problem for you.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue today, removing the pod cache and reinstalling from scratch did the trick for me.
close Xcode, delete pod files, then

```
rm -rf "${HOME}/Library/Caches/CocoaPods"
rm -rf "`pwd`/Pods/"
pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

pod 'Google/Analytics', '~> 2.0'

Fixed this for Google Analytics